# how to create a new git repo with 3 branches from 3 file trees

Tags: git

I've been using git for a bit but very simply and I have a question as to how to set up a remote git repository to which I can push three separate file trees which I have been working on, but keeping some folders on separate branches.

essentially the file tree can be summarized as follows:

local repo 1:

```
custom_folder containing custom_files - I'd like to keep these always unique to repo 1 (different branch?)

other folders, I'd like these to be the the same an all other local repos (right now they are mostly the same but not all the same)
```

local repo 2:

```
custom_folder containing custom_files - I'd like to keep these always unique to repo2 (different branch?)

other folders, I'd like these to be the same as repo 1 folders (same branch?)
```

local repo 3:

```
custom_folder containing custom_files - I'd like to keep these always unique to repo3 (different branch?)

other folders, I'd like these to be the same as repo 1 folders (same branch?)
```

Any advice on how to set up a remote repository to which I can push and pull each local repo maintaining the above conditions?

thanks for any help!
dani

Answer (score 0):

One branch for the common code, one branch for each project.

- Initialize the repository.
- Make a branch called `common`.
- Commit your common files in their own directory like `common/`.
- Delete `master` (just so nobody gets confused).
- For each project, make a branch off `common`.

When you make changes to the `common` branch and want to incorporate them into your projects, `git merge common project`.

If you make a change to the common code in your project branch, don't merge else the project code will wind up in the common branch.  Instead, checkout common and `git cherry-pick -n <commit>` the change.  The `-n` is so you have a chance to review what changes are being picked, to avoid accidentally pulling in project files.